# Migrating Content Fields in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, nodes

I have quite a few content types, and when I set it up I didn't think ahead and created an image field for each content type rather than one image field type.  Is there a way to add a common image field type and mass-convert the content types to use that one field?  Or do I have to manually migrate all of the currently populated fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module will help you to export all your image fields, and import them into one unified field; then, you can delete your obsolete fields.